# Ripple effect on shape drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop

Trying to do something really simple here and have looked up a bunch of SO resource, but to no avail. I am trying to get the ripple effect on a button which uses a `drawable` background of type of `shape drawable`. The relevant files:

**background_button:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#80ffffff" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

**ripple.xml** within the `drawable-v21` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_button"/>
</ripple>
```

**Button.xml:**

```
   <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ripple"


 />
```

What is wrong here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My advice would be not to use `<ripple` tag. I have 2 reasons: it is not that easy to do exactly what you want and you have to 2 different `.xml` files for every background. I don't like to have `drawable-v21` folder.

My solution is to wrap your `Button` with `FrameLayout` and use `android:foreground` attribute. This way you can have whatever background you want and you can keep the ripple effect.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Notice that I moved all the attributes and the id to `FrameLayout`. You should set `onClickListener` to `FrameLayout` instead of the `Button`.

Btw, `?attr/selectableItemBackground` is great. Use it as much as possible. It replaces blue Holo color with gray for old devices from Android 4.0 to 4.3.

Comment: That's what I am doing for a long time. It provides consistency from Api level 7 to 23. I hope it will work out for you

Comment: I copied the same thing you provided. Does the click listener need to be moved from the button or something?

Comment: Yes of course. :( Sorry that I forgot that. Click listener should be set to FrameLayout.

Comment: That did work. Thanks! One last question. Why use the attribute foreground.. instead of background on the framelayout?

Comment: It will be on the back if you use background. There will be ripple effect but it will be behind the other background and it will be invisible.

Comment: Why not simply put foreground element on the button directly ?

Comment: @AurélienLepage foreground tag is only available after Marshmallow on every View class. Before it is only available for FrameLayout.

Comment: @tasomaniac But property foreground is available from Api Level 1 for every view class...didnt get exactly your point..

Comment: Interesting solution, however, the ripple effect seems to fill the entire rectangle — not so good if the background is not a rectangular shape. Perhaps a mask will help contain it. (I haven't had a chance to try it yet.) Also, it's just a flash, not a ripple, on API 19, but it's better than nothing. Thanks for the idea, @tasomaniac!

Answer (score 24):

Try this.

ripple_effect.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:color="#2797e0"
tools:targetApi="lollipop">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#2797e0" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

button.xml

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"/>
```

build.gradle

```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: this does work, albeit the rectangle is not visible anymore

Comment: This works! And, of course, you have to remember that ripple itself uses shape drawable as a mask. So, to get both ripple AND shape displayed, one can go into background and the other one into foreground attributes.

Comment: This worked for me when i removed `android:id="@android:id/mask"` from `item`

Answer (score 14):

More simple solution - to use this drawable-xml as value of property "android:background" of the Button:

**drawable/bkg_ripple.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**button.xml:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/bkg_ripple"
/>
```

Answer (score 10):

That works for me
`drawable/rect.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF4C71F5" />
    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

and for ripple `drawable/rip.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and for your button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/nm"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rect"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:text="@string/vnm"
    android:textColor="@color/colorpr"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:foreground="@drawable/rip"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

I had the similar task. Let me explain how i solve it. It outputs circle imageViews with shadow and ripple effect not goes beyond circle boundaries.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_undo"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/iv_width_altmenu"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/iv_height_altmenu"
    android:src="@drawable/undo"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_buttons"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_effect"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons_inactive_coloring"
   />
```

The following provides ripple effect:

```
android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_effect"
```

The following provides circle imageView.

```
android:background="@drawable/buttons_inactive_coloring"
```

The following provides shadow:

```
android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_effect"
```

Another problem you may be probably face is ripple effect goes out of circle boundaries. In order to solve, use following file(ripple_effect.xml)

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/button_active"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/button_active" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

If you do not use the following :

```
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/button_active" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

ripple effect goes beyond circle boundaries and this does not looks nice. Be careful and takes it easy.

Answer (score 6):

This work for me..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/smooth_white"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_green_background" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/smooth_white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

The point is section

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_green_background" />
```

Comment: Unless, you have different button shape from mask shape, it would be cleaner to use same `@drawable/button_green_background` for background and for mask.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

- `card_back.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item>
          <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <corners android:radius="20dp" />
              <solid android:color="?attr/cardBGColor" />
              <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="?attr/borderColor"/>    
          </shape>
      </item>
  </selector>
  ```
- `card_ripple.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:color="#bbb">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/card_back" />
  </ripple>
  ```

And setup it this way: `android:background="@drawable/card_ripple"`

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/blue"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.1dp"
                android:color="#312D2D" />
            <solid android:color="#FFF" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
<com.abcd.ripplebutton.widget.RippleButton
        android:id="@+id/Summit"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:buttonColor="@color/Button"
        app:rippleColor="@color/white" />
```

For more See [this](http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-ripple-touch-effect-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me only this work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#cccccc">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

And in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_white"/>
```

Yes, it should be clickable